# Issue in Category page magento 2

Tags: magento2, pagination, category-listing

I am getting below error in system.log file.

```
  main.CRITICAL: Bucket does not exist [] []
```

My Main issue is in category list page and search result page I have 50 products inside the category and results. All are listed in the page. Even though pager is set to 12.

> **The pagination is not working correctly.**

I hope the problem is because of above error. How this can be resolved.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Did you install sample data in your project ?

Comment: @SaneerLadani, no I am not install sample data

Comment: refer this github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13823 @jafar

Comment: You have to set the Root category to Anchored -> 'Yes'. If it is set already as 'Yes', you have set it again to 'No' and  'Save' and then again into 'Yes' -> 'Save'.  This should resolve your problem @jafar

Comment: @divyasekar,Root category means Default category? I do not have any root category?

Comment: yes @jafarpinjar

Comment: @divyasekar, I did and checked , that didn't solve the issue

Comment: you can set developer mode and after check it or category page unnecessary condition remove

Comment: @RakeshDonga, Currently its in Developer mode, I hope i am not added any condition in category page.

Comment: check my answer @jafar

Answer (score 1):

php file at path:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection.php

Replace the code line:

```
throw new StateException(__(‘Bucket does not exist’));
```

with the code line:(comment it )

```
//throw new StateException(__(‘Bucket does not exist’));
```

Comment: by this we can comment the error , but pagination will work? @divya

Comment: pagination is working or not

Comment: no its not working for me, my issue is that only, @divya

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from a facet field so it's possible that the wrong behaviour is related to this.

Unfortunately I can give you only general tips based on your question but maybe they help you:

- Try to rebuild the `Catalog Search` index that might help.
- A further step would be to deactivate the facet attributes one by one and see if that changes the behaviour.

Comment: I have two questions as per the answer.
1.Where i need to deactivate facet? what are facet attributes?
2. rebulild Catalog Search means re index?

Comment: I did full re index and tried, still facing same issue

Comment: 1. each product attribute has an option "use in layer navigation", setting this to "no" will deactivate the facet

Comment: Does it effect with pagination?

Comment: I hope by making that setting as No, Pagination doesn't works correctly, because I did and tried..