# How to move sku in price block in product detail page and how to move title in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-view

How to move SKU  in price block in product detail page in Magento 2

screenshot

[image]

i was tried with below code

```
 <move element="product.info.sku" destination="product.price.tier" after="-"/>
```

and
**How to move title  in product detail page  alone** 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep below code inside xml file body tag in your xml file,

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.price" after="-"/>
```

for title

```
<move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.review"/>
```

Comment: Its working @rakesh

Comment: Please change before to after or accept my edited code

Comment: how to move a product title @rakesh plz refer a edited question

Comment: check my answer @divyasekar

Comment: I will check and update you @rakesh

Comment: i tried it Its not working still title in same position @rakesh

Comment: @divyasekar i have updated my answer check now

Comment: Let me check and update you @rakesh

Comment: @RakeshDonga, I am facing below issue, can you please look into it, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/259796/issue-in-category-page-magento-2/

Comment: refer this https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13823 @jafar

Comment: @divyasekar, i referred here before posting my question, but that didn't resolved for me

Comment: let me check and tell you @jafar

Comment: above code working ?@divyasekar

Comment: its working @rakesh  in my case before="product.info.price"