# Magento 2 display configurable product Price Range in product page

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price

I want to display the price range for configurable products on the product page.

Comment: you can try do it like this link https://www.classyllama.com/blog/configurable-product-price-ranges-m2

Comment: I have tried but not working in PDP 
Working fine on PLP

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/146495)

Comment: hi @MagentoDeveloper did u got the solution for this? I have the same requirement can u please provide me the correct answer

Comment: @MagentoDeveloper classyllama.com/blog/configurable-product-price-ranges-m2  the is not working did U find the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps.

**Step 1:** Create a layout file `catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml` on this path `app/design/frontend/{{companyname}}/{{themename}}/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/layout/catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.price">
    <block class="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" name="wk.info.pricerange"  template="Magento_ConfigurableProduct::product/price_range.phtml" />
</referenceBlock>
```

**Step 2:** Create template file `price_range.phtml` on this path `app/design/frontend/{{companyname}}/{{themename}}/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/product/price_range.phtml`

```
<?php
$currentProduct = $this->getProduct();
$regularPrice = $currentProduct->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price');
?>
<div class='price-box'>
    <span class="price">
        <?php
            echo $regularPrice->getMinRegularAmount().'-'.$regularPrice->getMaxRegularAmount();
        ?>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried but not working in PDP 
Working fine on PLP

Comment: @Kadivar, can you please look into this issue? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/259796/issue-in-category-page-magento-2/

Comment: @PrashantPatel i have updated my answer please check it again. now it is working for me in product page.

Comment: @PrashantPatel if it is working fine, please accept my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I Have Created a Module for Showing Product Min and Max Prices into Price Range Slider View.

You can find the Module from My GIT HUB Repository - https://github.com/vishalthakurit/Magento2-priceRange-Slider/tree/master

**Another Solution -**

In your module structure create a layout file `catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml`, in my case the file path is `app/code/{{CompanyName}}/{{ModuleName}}/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.price">
            <block class="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" name="vishal.info.pricerange"  template="{{CompanyName}}_{{ModuleName}}::product/price_range.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now, we will create template file `price_range.phtml` at path `app/code/{{CompanyName}}/{{ModuleName}}/view/frontend/templates/price_range.phtml`.

```
<?php
$currentProduct = $this->getProduct();
$regularPrice = $currentProduct->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price');
?>
<div class='price-box'>
    <span class="price">
        <?php
            echo '<b>Min : </b>'.$regularPrice->getMinRegularAmount().' - <b>Max : </b>'.$regularPrice->getMaxRegularAmount();
        ?>
    </span>
</div>
```

**It will look like the attached Screenshot:-**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Min& Max values will update as per the size & color options selected?

Comment: Hi @vishal I would like to display the price range at the As low as price box place can u guide me how to do?

Comment: @NagarajuK you can use JQuery UI Range Slider - https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range
in your custom file and override the default price block section.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/309861/magento2-display-price-range-on-pdp-configrable-product

Comment: @NagarajuK please check my Answer on https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/309861/magento2-display-price-range-on-pdp-configrable-product/309902#309902