# Magento2 display price range on PDP configrable product

Tags: magento2, price, pdp

I would like to display the price range for configurable products on the product details page.
I have followed some references but no luck

app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/base/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configurable" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_ModuleName::product/price/final_price.phtml</item>                            
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</layout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I Have **Created a Module for Showing Product Min and Max Prices into Price Range Slider View**.

You can find the Module from My GIT HUB Repository - https://github.com/vishalthakurit/Magento2-priceRange-Slider/tree/master

Layout File will be - `app/code/Tecgenome/PriceSlider/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Tecgenome_PriceSlider::css/jquery-ui.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.price">
            <block class="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" name="wk.info.pricerange" template="Tecgenome_PriceSlider::product/price_range.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
        <move element="wk.info.pricerange" destination="product.info.main" after="page.main.title" />
    </body>
</page>
```

It will show like this (there may be some CSS issues, you can fix those accordingly)

[image]

Hope It will Help you !!!

Comment: thanks, @vishal for sharing can we display the price range as per my reference screenshot. please suggest

Comment: @NagarajuK yes we can do that....just need to changed the catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml file code as above i have just updated.

Comment: @NagarajuK check the updated Answer.

Comment: @NagarajuK If it worked for you.... can you please mark it GREEN.